Interpreting bit-packed data in Python with structs and ctypes: misaligned results
I have some data stored in a bit-packed format, which I'm trying to extract with Python.  Specifically these are old bitmap fonts, where:

each line of a glyph is a group of n bits (where n is the character width).
only the first line is guaranteed to start on a byte boundary.
the bitmap data for each glyph is packed into a big-endian series of bytes.

For example, here's the big-endian hex data for one glyph, which is 9 bits wide:
1F 1F DB 79 3D BF FE F7 86 CE 3E
If we break this up manually, we can see that this bit pattern represents a little smiley face:
8-bit bytes:        9-bit chunks:   character (0='.', 1='$'):
                                         
0x1F = 00011111     000111110       ...$$$$$. 
0x1F = 00011111     001111111       ..$$$$$$$ 
0xDB = 11011011     011011011       .$$.$$.$$ 
0x79 = 01111001     110010011       $$..$..$$ 
0x3D = 00111101     110110111       $$.$$.$$$ 
0xBF = 10111111     111111111       $$$$$$$$$ 
0xFE = 11111110     101111011       $.$$$$.$$ 
0xF7 = 11110111     110000110       $$....$$. 
0x86 = 10000110     110011100       $$..$$$.. 
0xCE = 11001110     011111000       .$$$$$... 
0x3E = 00111110                               

So I tried to do the same in Python, but I can't get the data to align properly when packed.
Here's what I have so far - just some test code to see if I can get the expected result from this particular piece of data.
Note the choice of field_type, since that seems to be the root of my problems:
import struct
import ctypes

field_type = ctypes.c_ulonglong

class PackedBitmap(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [ ('line00', field_type, 9),
                 ('line01', field_type, 9),
                 ('line02', field_type, 9),
                 ('line03', field_type, 9),
                 ('line04', field_type, 9),
                 ('line05', field_type, 9),
                 ('line06', field_type, 9),
                 ('line07', field_type, 9),
                 ('line08', field_type, 9),
                 ('line09', field_type, 9) ]

bm = PackedBitmap()

struct.pack_into('>11s', bm, 0, 
                 b'\x1F\x1F\xDB\x79\x3D\xBF\xFE\xF7\x86\xCE\x3E')

for field in bm._fields_:
    bin_str = f'{getattr(bm, field[0]):09b}'
    print(bin_str + '     ' + bin_str.replace('0','.').replace('1','$'))

But no matter which C type I pick for my PackedBitmap's fields, I can't get the output right.  There are always errors, and the size of the data type seems to determine where the first error will occur.
field_type = ctypes.c_ulonglong:
000111110     ...$$$$$.
001111111     ..$$$$$$$
011011011     .$$.$$.$$
110010011     $$..$..$$
110110111     $$.$$.$$$
111111111     $$$$$$$$$
101111011     $.$$$$.$$
100001101     $....$$.$   # <- first error
100111000     $..$$$...
111110000     $$$$$....

field_type = ctypes.c_uint32:
000111110     ...$$$$$.
001111111     ..$$$$$$$
011011011     .$$.$$.$$
001111011     ..$$$$.$$   # <- first error
011111111     .$$$$$$$$
111110111     $$$$$.$$$
100001101     $....$$.$
100111000     $..$$$...
111110000     $$$$$....
000000000     .........

field_type = ctypes.c_uint16:
000111110     ...$$$$$.
110110110     $$.$$.$$.   # <- first error
001111011     ..$$$$.$$
111111101     $$$$$$$.$
100001101     $....$$.$
001111100     ..$$$$$..
000000000     .........
000000000     .........
000000000     .........
000000000     .........

I'm not sure what's going on here:  a length of 9 bits fits comfortably within all these field types (64, 32, and 16 bits respectively), so shouldn't this be packed as expected?  What am I missing, and how to fix this?

Ctypes is apparently not allowing a bitfield of type X to span more than one element of type X; for example, with 64-bit X, you get seven 9-bit fields for a total of 63 bits, then one bit gets skipped so that the next field starts in a new ulonglong element.  There's no way you're going to be able to parse your bitmap data like this.  I would suggest the bitarray package instead: it has a .frombytes() method that can directly read your data, and then you can extract arbitrary-sized rows of the bitmap just via slicing.

You can see this if you print PackedBitmap.lineXY. It will show you the offset for byte and bit. Depending on the field_type you can see where it starts to go wrong. Maybe this is worth reporting to the CPython maintainers. But note, that in C this also does not work.

@jasonharper Thanks - I was looking at bitstring but bitarray may be an even better tool for the job.

It looks like the ctypes.Strucuture has problems when crossing byte boundaries (depending on the field type).
We can print the offset the fields use:
print(PackedBitmap.line00)
...
print(PackedBitmap.line09)

Which gives us
<Field type=c_ulonglong_be, ofs=0:55, bits=9> # 1
<Field type=c_ulonglong_be, ofs=0:46, bits=9> # 2
<Field type=c_ulonglong_be, ofs=0:37, bits=9> # 3
<Field type=c_ulonglong_be, ofs=0:28, bits=9> # 4
<Field type=c_ulonglong_be, ofs=0:19, bits=9> # 5
<Field type=c_ulonglong_be, ofs=0:10, bits=9> # 6
<Field type=c_ulonglong_be, ofs=0:1, bits=9>  # 7
<Field type=c_ulonglong_be, ofs=8:55, bits=9> # 8
<Field type=c_ulonglong_be, ofs=8:46, bits=9> # 9
<Field type=c_ulonglong_be, ofs=8:37, bits=9> # 10


The first field goes from bits 55 to 63. This is fine
The seventh goes from bits 1 to 9. This is also fine
The eights goes from bits 55 to 63 in the second byte. So we are missing bit 0 of byte 0.

This may be a bug, or at least unexpected. When you switch to other data types you will see that the error happens first when switching to the next byte.
It could be worth reporting this to the CPython devs. In my opinion this should at least be mentioned in the documentation. I could not find such a hint.
However, here is an implementation that doesn't use neither ctypes nor struct:

it concats the bytes as 1s and 0s together into one large string
then it splits them into parts of length 9

from collections.abc import Iterator
from itertools import batched

raw = b'\x1F\x1F\xDB\x79\x3D\xBF\xFE\xF7\x86\xCE\x3E'


def regroup_bits(buffer: bytes, bits: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    binary = ''.join(f'{byte:08b}' for byte in buffer)

    return (''.join(batch) for batch in batched(binary, bits))


for i in regroup_bits(raw, 9):
    print(i.replace('0', '.').replace('1', '$'))

This could be optimised to be more memory friendly by not building one large string, but instead only as many bits as you need and then yield a 9-bit value.
Also note, this implementation does not pad the last value.

Bitfields are implementation-defined in C.  It's common (I've never seen it implemented differently) to pad to the next element if a bitfield won't completely fit in an element.  ctypes follows the convention.

Thanks for the insight on element boundaries... yeah, I can see what's going on there.
The string-concatenation approach is plenty elegant enough and seems to work fine!  I might try something with bitarray as well, but for now this seems like the most flexible solution for supporting different widths.

There are multiple ways to tackle this. Here's one that's more friendly for Python developers, which relies on string operations. Due to that, it's waay slower (and I'd say less elegant) than a bit manipulating counterpart.
code00.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import string
import struct
import sys


def glyph(data, bit_width=9, display_chars=".$"):
    binary = "".join(f"{e:08b}" for e in data)  # Convert to binary string
    tbl = binary.maketrans("01", display_chars)
    text = binary.translate(tbl)  # Replace 0s and 1s by the given chars
    rows, last = divmod(len(data) * 8, bit_width)
    if last:
        text += display_chars[0] * (bit_width - last)  # Pad the string with 0s correspondent (if neccessary)
        rows += 1
    ret = []
    for row_idx in range(rows):
        ret.append(text[bit_width * row_idx: bit_width * (row_idx + 1)])  # Split the string in chunks with the required length
    return tuple(ret)


def main(*argv):
    data = b"\x1F\x1F\xDB\x79\x3D\xBF\xFE\xF7\x86\xCE\x3E"
    print(data)
    lines = glyph(data)

    print("Glyph:")
    for line in lines:
        print(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)

Output:

(qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q078769490]> python ./code00.py 
Python 3.8.19 (default, Apr  6 2024, 17:58:10) [GCC 11.4.0] 064bit on linux

b'\x1f\x1f\xdby=\xbf\xfe\xf7\x86\xce>'
Glyph:
...$$$$$.
..$$$$$$$
.$$.$$.$$
$$..$..$$
$$.$$.$$$
$$$$$$$$$
$.$$$$.$$
$$....$$.
$$..$$$..
.$$$$$...

Done.



You are better-off handling the bits yourself, in Python code, than relying on ctypes to do that - ctypes won't be much faster for bit manipulation in its structs anyway, and it will "think in the container data type" - that is, your bitfields have to be contained in a C data type, like int64 - that is why you get misalignments when crossing the boundary of the first 8 bytes (64bits), and why that varies when changing the container type to other than ulong.
Turns out it is easier to create an iterator that will pick each byte in the sequence, and yield the bits in turn - and then, wrapping it with another iterator that groups those bits together into your glyph lines.
class GlyphRender:
    def __init__(self, byte_seq, width=9, ones="#", zeros=" "):
        self.byte_seq = byte_seq
        self.width = width
        self.ones = ones
        self.zeros = zeros
    def bit_iter(self):
        for byte in self.byte_seq:
            for power in range(7, -1, -1):
                yield bool(byte & 2 ** power)
    def __iter__(self):
        line = ""
        for bit in self.bit_iter():
            line += self.ones if bit else self.zeros
            if len(line) == self.width:
                yield line
                line = ""
        if line:
            yield line
    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(self)

And running this on the REPL:
In [49]: print(GlyphRender(b'\x1F\x1F\xDB\x79\x3D\xBF\xFE\xF7\x86\xCE\x3E'))
   #####
  #######
 ## ## ##
##  #  ##
## ## ###
#########
# #### ##
##    ##
##  ###
 #####


Not that I'm recommending to do it this way, but here's a way to do it in ctypes.  Use properties to construct the 9-bit fields.  You could get even fancier with custom descriptors to get rid of the repetition, but I'm not going to go there.  Note that a different Python implementation (This is Python for Windows 64-bit) may not work due to bitfields being implementation-defined.
import ctypes as ct

class PackedBitmap(ct.BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = (('_line01', ct.c_ubyte, 8),
                ('_line02', ct.c_ubyte, 1),
                ('_line11', ct.c_ubyte, 7),
                ('_line12', ct.c_ubyte, 2),
                ('_line21', ct.c_ubyte, 6),
                ('_line22', ct.c_ubyte, 3),
                ('_line31', ct.c_ubyte, 5),
                ('_line32', ct.c_ubyte, 4),
                ('_line41', ct.c_ubyte, 4),
                ('_line42', ct.c_ubyte, 5),
                ('_line51', ct.c_ubyte, 3),
                ('_line52', ct.c_ubyte, 6),
                ('_line61', ct.c_ubyte, 2),
                ('_line62', ct.c_ubyte, 7),
                ('_line71', ct.c_ubyte, 1),
                ('_line72', ct.c_ubyte, 8),
                ('_line81', ct.c_ubyte, 8),
                ('_line82', ct.c_ubyte, 1),
                ('_line91', ct.c_ubyte, 7))

    @property
    def line00(self):
        return self._line01 << 1 | self._line02
    @line00.setter
    def line00(self, value):
        self._line01 = value >> 1
        self._line02 = value & 0x01

    @property
    def line01(self):
        return self._line11 << 2 | self._line12
    @line01.setter
    def line01(self, value):
        self._line11 = value >> 2
        self._line12 = value & 0x03

    @property
    def line02(self):
        return self._line21 << 3 | self._line22
    @line02.setter
    def line02(self, value):
        self._line21 = value >> 3
        self._line22 = value & 0x07

    @property
    def line03(self):
        return self._line31 << 4 | self._line32
    @line03.setter
    def line03(self, value):
        self._line31 = value >> 4
        self._line32 = value & 0x0F

    @property
    def line04(self):
        return self._line41 << 5 | self._line42
    @line04.setter
    def line04(self, value):
        self._line41 = value >> 5
        self._line42 = value & 0x1F

    @property
    def line05(self):
        return self._line51 << 6 | self._line52
    @line05.setter
    def line05(self, value):
        self._line51 = value >> 6
        self._line52 = value & 0x3F

    @property
    def line06(self):
        return self._line61 << 7 | self._line62
    @line06.setter
    def line06(self, value):
        self._line61 = value >> 7
        self._line62 = value & 0xEF

    @property
    def line07(self):
        return self._line71 << 8 | self._line72
    @line07.setter
    def line07(self, value):
        self._line71 = value >> 8
        self._line72 = value

    @property
    def line08(self):
        return self._line81 << 1 | self._line82
    @line08.setter
    def line08(self, value):
        self._line81 = value >> 1
        self._line82 = value & 0x01

    @property
    def line09(self):
        return self._line91 << 2
    @line09.setter
    def line09(self, value):
        self._line91 = value >> 2
        self._line92 = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return (f'PackedBitmap(0b{self.line00:09b},\n'
                f'             0b{self.line01:09b},\n'
                f'             0b{self.line02:09b},\n'
                f'             0b{self.line03:09b},\n'
                f'             0b{self.line04:09b},\n'
                f'             0b{self.line05:09b},\n'
                f'             0b{self.line06:09b},\n'
                f'             0b{self.line07:09b},\n'
                f'             0b{self.line08:09b},\n'
                f'             0b{self.line09:09b})\n')

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'{self.line00:09b}\n'
                f'{self.line01:09b}\n'
                f'{self.line02:09b}\n'
                f'{self.line03:09b}\n'
                f'{self.line04:09b}\n'
                f'{self.line05:09b}\n'
                f'{self.line06:09b}\n'
                f'{self.line07:09b}\n'
                f'{self.line08:09b}\n'
                f'{self.line09:09b}\n').translate(str.maketrans('01', ' \N{FULL BLOCK}'))

bm = PackedBitmap.from_buffer_copy(bytes.fromhex('1F 1F DB 79 3D BF FE F7 86 CE 3E'))
print(bytes(bm).hex(' '))
print(repr(bm))
print(bm)
bm.line00 = 0b100000000
bm.line01 = 0b010000000
bm.line02 = 0b001000000
bm.line03 = 0b000100000
bm.line04 = 0b000010000
bm.line05 = 0b000001000
bm.line06 = 0b000000100
bm.line07 = 0b000000010
bm.line08 = 0b000000001
bm.line09 = 0b111111111

# Structure is 88 bits (11 bytes), but 10 lines of 9 bits is 90.
# Last two bits of line09 are forced zero.
print(bytes(bm).hex(' '))
print(repr(bm))
print(bm)

Output:
1f 1f db 79 3d bf fe f7 86 ce 3e
PackedBitmap(0b000111110,
             0b001111111,
             0b011011011,
             0b110010011,
             0b110110111,
             0b111111111,
             0b101111011,
             0b110000110,
             0b110011100,
             0b011111000)

   █████ 
  ███████
 ██ ██ ██
██  █  ██
██ ██ ███
█████████
█ ████ ██
██    ██ 
██  ███  
 █████   

80 20 08 02 00 80 20 08 02 00 ff
PackedBitmap(0b100000000,
             0b010000000,
             0b001000000,
             0b000100000,
             0b000010000,
             0b000001000,
             0b000000100,
             0b000000010,
             0b000000001,
             0b111111100)

█        
 █       
  █      
   █     
    █    
     █   
      █  
       █ 
        █
███████  


you probably could do better with  just quiting ctypes and work with a "bytearray"  - and then use a class with __getitem__ and __setitem__ methos if you want to be able to change the contents of the struct. This can avoild all the hard-coded properties, and even work for varying bit-width data.

@jsbueno As I said, I'm not recommending it, just showing a way with ctypes for the OP's implementation.  It has been useful for me when I had an odd C structure that had a field that crossed over a natural boundary in a real-life situation.

Yeah, I'm definitely not wedded to ctypes (FWIW, I don't really need the option to change the contents - only to export the data into a more convenient format).

In a comment it was mentioned the OP wants "...only to export the data into a more convenient format".
Here is a class implementation to do that:
import ctypes as ct

class PackedBitmap:
    def __init__(self, byte_data):
        # store bytes in a Python int with two trailing pad bits
        self._data = int.from_bytes(byte_data, 'big') << 2

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # Support only integer indices (no slices) for 10 9-bit elements.
        if index < 0 or index > 9:
            raise IndexError('list index out of range')
        # Shift and mask the 9 bits represented by the index
        return self._data >> (81 - index * 9) & 0x1FF

    def __str__(self):
        '''Pretty display.'''
        xlat = str.maketrans('01', ' \N{FULL BLOCK}')
        return '\n'.join([f'{n:09b}'.translate(xlat) for n in self])

    def __repr__(self):
        '''Debug display.'''
        return f'PackedBitmap({(bm._data >> 2).to_bytes(11)!r})'

    def __iter__(self):
        # Make object iterable
        for i in range(len(self)):
            yield self[i]

    def __len__(self):
        # Make object fixed length
        return 10

bm = PackedBitmap(bytes([0x1f,0x1f,0xdb,0x79,0x3d,0xbf,0xfe,0xf7,0x86,0xce,0x3e]))
print(bm)        # graphic display
print(repr(bm))  # debug display
print(list(bm))  # convert 9-bit data to a Python list
for n in bm:     # iterate and custom display
    print(f'0x{n:03X} {n:09b}')

Output:
   █████ 
  ███████
 ██ ██ ██
██  █  ██
██ ██ ███
█████████
█ ████ ██
██    ██ 
██  ███  
 █████   
PackedBitmap(b'\x1f\x1f\xdby=\xbf\xfe\xf7\x86\xce>')
[62, 127, 219, 403, 439, 511, 379, 390, 412, 248]
0x03E 000111110
0x07F 001111111
0x0DB 011011011
0x193 110010011
0x1B7 110110111
0x1FF 111111111
0x17B 101111011
0x186 110000110
0x19C 110011100
0x0F8 011111000


Thanks!  To elaborate a bit, that 'more convenient format' would be byte-aligned, and the character width can be arbitrary (within reasonable bounds, say <=32); 9 was an example involving a specific file.
I went with a variant of Wombatz's string-based idea, which was trivial to adapt to these needs, although your solution would likely be more efficient and extensible otherwise.
